# how to get full qtablewidget cell content while hovering it

Tags: c++, qt

Do you have any ideas how to get full qtablewidget cell content while hovering it, the column size is smaller than content size so i would like to get all cell content while hovering the cell like we get link while hovering reference on Internet

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to show the content of the cell while the mouse is on top? and where do you want to show it?

Comment: eyllanesc, i would like to show it like reference like in browser if it is possible  on the bottom of the cell

Comment: If you look at the browser that widget is similar to a QStatusBar, so that's what you could do, another option is to add a custom widget below the QTableWidget. Which one do you want?

Comment: the answer is not simple, we can get the row and column, but getting the text will depend on the type of widget you want to get the text since the methods are different. You could tell me the widgets you use for each column.

Comment: `v->model()->data( index, Qt::TextRole ).toString()`. Btw, read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html